# Reference request: Spec A_* is the automorphism group of the additive formal group law

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, formal-groups

Dear all,

I'm seeking a reference for a claim made in lecture 8 of Jacob Lurie's chromatic homotopy theory notes (http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/252xnotes/Lecture8.pdf). More particularly, Theorem 6 of this lecture states that (say over $\mathbb{F}_2$, so that things are commutative) the spectrum $\mathbb{G} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{A}_*$ of the dual Steenrod algebra $\mathcal{A}_*$ is the automorphism group of the additive formal group law, in the obvious sense.

Lurie argues convincingly that $\mathbb{G}$ does act on the additive formal group law, but I don't think he attempts to prove that this action gives an isomorphism with the automorphism group. I'd be grateful if someone could give me a reference for this fact.

Cheers,

Saul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIT OpenCourseWare has some [notes from a course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-917-topics-in-algebraic-topology-the-sullivan-conjecture-fall-2007/lecture-notes/) that Lurie taught in 2007.  I believe [the lecture on the dual Steenrod algebra](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-917-topics-in-algebraic-topology-the-sullivan-conjecture-fall-2007/lecture-notes/lecture13.pdf) has a proof of the claim.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a reference in print, it's in Ravenel's book *Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres*.  See the comments after the proof of Theorem A2.2.18.  (This book is [available online](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mu.html#repub), and you want Appendix 2.)